# WCF - EndpointNotFoundException

Tags: wcf, wcf-endpoint

I have the following scenario:
Project A contains 2 interfaces A, and B and two service endpoints, EndpointA and EndpointB, each implementing the matching interface.
I have a unit test Project, which uses Cassinini to test the services. I use a proxy I generated with svcutil to create client objects in my unit test. 
Here is my app.config from the unit test project:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttp" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="5242880" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="5242880" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAdministration" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                        maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IRetrieval" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IModification" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>      
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>      
  <endpoint address="http://localhost/MyServiceA.svc/MyServiceA"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IRetrieval"
      contract="IRetrieval" name="BasicHttpBinding_IRetrieval" />
  <endpoint address="http://localhost/MyServiceB.svc/MyService"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IModification"
      contract="IModification" name="BasicHttpBinding_IModification" />      
</client>
```

When I call ServiceA, it works fine. However, when I call ServiceB, I get the following error message:

> Test method MyMethod threw exception: 
>   System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: The message with To 'http://localhost/MyServiceB.svc/MyServiceB' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.

What's happening? Thanks.

Comment: And how did you configure service endpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cassini almost never listens at port 80. You need to find out the port Cassini listens to and make it fixed (using project properties/web and change the default to a fixed port number) and update the endpoint:

```
 <endpoint address="http://localhost:<PORTNUMBER>/MyServiceB.svc/MyService"
  binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IModification"
  contract="IModification" name="BasicHttpBinding_IModification" />
```

Comment: Aliostad, How come the other service client works fine - they are both defined in the same proxy and have identical config entries except for names?